# Aspnetboilerplate Angular File Upload

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to build a file upload with the aspnetboilerplate .net core and angular spa.  I am new to the framework and really like it but can't get the file upload working.

First if this can be done in a service without a controller that would be my preferred solution.

Currently I am trying a controller with the code below but it doesn't work

Here is .ts component method to upload file.

```
   upload(files) {
       if (files.length === 0)
           return;

        const formData = new FormData();

        for (let file of files)
            formData.append(file.name, file);

        const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `api/FileUpload/UploadFile`, formData, {
            reportProgress: true,
        });

        this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
                this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
                this.reqMessage = event.body.toString();
        });
    }
```

I put the controller in the myapp web host controller folder (The same folder where the antiforgery controller exist)

Here is my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileUploadController : myappControllerBase
{

    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public FileUploadController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            return Json("Upload Successful.");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Not sure if the formData is setup correct but it does not reach my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the sample code that uploads profile picture...

**UploadProfilePicture() controller method:**

```
public class FileUploadController : myappControllerBase
{
      public UploadProfilePictureOutput UploadProfilePicture()
            {
                try
                {
                    var profilePictureFile = Request.Form.Files.First();

                    //Check input
                    if (profilePictureFile == null)
                    {
                        throw new UserFriendlyException("An error occurred!");
                    }

                    if (profilePictureFile.Length > 9999999) //change the max value
                    {
                        throw new UserFriendlyException("Picture exceeds max size!));
                    }

                    byte[] fileBytes;
                    using (var stream = profilePictureFile.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        fileBytes = stream.GetAllBytes();
                    }

                    //Save new picture
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(profilePictureFile.FileName);
                    var tempFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileInfo.Extension;
                    var tempFilePath = Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\upload", tempFileName);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(temp1FilePath, fileBytes);

                    using (var bmpImage = new Bitmap(tempFilePath))
                    {
                        return new UploadProfilePictureOutput
                        {
                            FileName = tempFileName,
                            Width = bmpImage.Width,
                            Height = bmpImage.Height
                        };
                    }
                }
                catch (UserFriendlyException ex)
                {
                    return new UploadProfilePictureOutput(new ErrorInfo(ex.Message));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**UploadProfilePictureOutput.cs:**

```
public class UploadProfilePictureOutput : ErrorInfo
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public int Width { get; set; }

        public int Height { get; set; }

        public UploadProfilePictureOutput()
        {

        }

        public UploadProfilePictureOutput(ErrorInfo error)
        {
            Code = error.Code;
            Details = error.Details;
            Message = error.Message;
            ValidationErrors = error.ValidationErrors;
        }
}
```

**Angular side:**

```
import { IAjaxResponse } from '@abp/abpHttpInterceptor';
import { TokenService } from '@abp/auth/token.service';
import { Component, Injector, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/common/app-component-base';
import { ProfileServiceProxy, UpdateProfilePictureInput } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { FileUploader, FileUploaderOptions } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'changeProfilePictureModal',
    templateUrl: './change-profile-picture-modal.component.html'
})
export class ChangeProfilePictureModalComponent extends AppComponentBase {

    @ViewChild('changeProfilePictureModal') modal: ModalDirective;

    public active = false;
    public uploader: FileUploader;
    public temporaryPictureUrl: string;
    public saving = false;

    private maxProfilPictureBytesUserFriendlyValue = 5;
    private temporaryPictureFileName: string;
    private _uploaderOptions: FileUploaderOptions = {};

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private _profileService: ProfileServiceProxy,
        private _tokenService: TokenService
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }

    initializeModal(): void {
        this.active = true;
        this.temporaryPictureUrl = '';
        this.temporaryPictureFileName = '';
        this.initFileUploader();
    }

    show(): void {
        this.initializeModal();
        this.modal.show();
    }

    close(): void {
        this.active = false;
        this.imageChangedEvent = '';
        this.uploader.clearQueue();
        this.modal.hide();
    }

    imageChangedEvent: any = '';

    fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
        this.imageChangedEvent = event;
    }

    imageCroppedFile(file: File) {
        var files: File[] = [file];
        this.uploader.clearQueue();
        this.uploader.addToQueue(files);
    }

    initFileUploader(): void {
        this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: "http://localhost:22742/Profile/UploadProfilePicture' });
        this._uploaderOptions.autoUpload = false;
        this._uploaderOptions.authToken = 'Bearer ' + this._tokenService.getToken();
        this._uploaderOptions.removeAfterUpload = true;
        this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
            file.withCredentials = false;
        };

        this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status) => {
            const resp = <IAjaxResponse>JSON.parse(response);
            if (resp.success) {
                this.updateProfilePicture(resp.result.fileName);
            } else {
                this.message.error(resp.error.message);
            }
        };

        this.uploader.setOptions(this._uploaderOptions);
    }

    updateProfilePicture(fileName: string): void {
        const input = new UpdateProfilePictureInput();
        input.fileName = fileName;
        input.x = 0;
        input.y = 0;
        input.width = 0;
        input.height = 0;

        this.saving = true;
        this._profileService.updateProfilePicture(input)
            .pipe(finalize(() => { this.saving = false; }))
            .subscribe(() => {
                abp.event.trigger('profilePictureChanged');
                this.close();
            });
    }

    save(): void {
        this.uploader.uploadAll();
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add bearer token to your ajax upload. Beside, you need to grant write permission to the physical upload directory in your IIS on production.